# WSO 2.5 Found on Apache

Tags: apache, permissions

I have found on my web server the file wp-conf.php which when you call it from the browser with a url parameter like wp-conf.php?t7831n=**any value** shows an interface where you can control the entire server. I am using Joomla 1.5 on the server which has a lot of vulnerabilities.

The code for this WSO thing that I decoded can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/nroussi/6222944)

Besides migrating to a newer version of Joomla, I would like to make sure that all directories are clean of any malicious files. I run chkrootkit and it says that everything is fine. Also, what would the correct permissions need to be on the /var/www directory. After reading quite a few posts, I have them now as 755 (except a temp that needed 777) and the owner is the main user with group owner www-data that the main user is a part of.

Any help/insight is much appreciated. The server is running ubuntu 10.04 and is completely patched. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all: please disallow any network-connections in/out via iptables, except ssh. chance is given your server is part of a botnet already.

running an outdated $whatever is bad, as you experienced, see  [[1]](http://developer.joomla.org/security/news/563-20130801-core-unauthorised-uploads), [[2]](http://krebsonsecurity.com/2013/08/simple-hack-threatens-oudated-joomla-sites/)

for your second part: you dont know if files are modified and malicious stuff included, or any hidden file dropped into your docroot. finding such stuff needs some experience though. you shoudl also check /tmp for hidden directories or
your network-config.

what you can do: grab clean joomla-sources and do a setup with your database; but check your database for stuff that does not belong there.

you can check your website with [sucuri](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/)
or your server-ip with [robtex](http://ip.robtex.com/) to see, if your site is already known as bad; google-safebrowsing might give another hint.
and google has a page to help/inform people like you: [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/)

you should also check your logs for that ip that accessed that wp-conf.php.

Comment: I checked the links. Now the server is sending random emails. I installed nullmailer on it and disabled it so all mail just gets in the queue. Is there a way to see from where the mails are generated?

Comment: you probably have an irc-bot running or a hidden php-backdoor. take your server offline.

Comment: I dont think that your solution is an acceptable answer on this forum. Take my server offline? Anyway I am using this for now [link](http://www.cirt.net/nikto2)